# How do I access a variable from another output

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build my first Shiny app at the moment and and having some issues. Is it possible to get access to a variable from a different output object? I'm trying to print the table in the first tab and show the individual plots on separate tabs, even better if I can show all 3 on 1 tab.

```
mainPanel(
tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("dataTable")),
tabPanel("xy Chart", plotOutput("xyChart")),
tabPanel("yz Chart", plotOutput("yzChart"))
                    )
    )
)
)
)
server <- function(input, output) {

output$dataTable <- renderTable({
    x <- rnorm(100, mean = 1)
    y <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
    z <- rnorm(100, mean = 0.5)
    dataTable <- cbind(x,y,z)
})
output$xyChart <- renderPlot({
    plot(x,y)
})
```

Comment: Have you tried adding more `*Output` entries to an individual `tabPanel`? What I mean is i.e. `tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("dataTable"), plotOutput("xyChart"))`. Notice that `tabPanel` takes UI element*s* (see description under `...` of the help file `?shiny::tabPanel`).

Comment: I'm not able to display a chart yet so I can't tell if another *Output element will work. Thanks for the suggestion though. I will try it once I can get one of the plots working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't already, would take a look at the `shiny` tutorials [available](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/).

Instead of including your data in a single `output` inside of `server`, you could declare these variables elsewhere. Since you are creating a `shiny` app, you might be interested in changing these variables, and having the other `outputs` automatically update.

If that is true, you might want to use `reactiveValues` or create a `reactive` function.

Here's an example below. By using `reactiveValues`, when you read a value from it (like x, y, or z) the calling expression takes a reactive dependency on that value (and will update with changes made to it). Whenever you modify those values, it will notify all reactive functions that depend on that value.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
      tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")),
      tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
      tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  my_data <- reactiveValues(
    x = rnorm(100, mean = 1),
    y = rnorm(100, mean = 0),
    z = rnorm(100, mean = 0.5)
  )

  output$table <- renderTable({
    data.frame(my_data$x, my_data$y, my_data$z)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(my_data$x, my_data$y)
  })

  output$summary <- renderText({
    "Summary Goes Here"
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And if you want all 3 on one panel (as described in comments), use this for your `ui`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                tabPanel("All 3", 
                         plotOutput("plot"),
                         verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
                         tableOutput("table")
                         )
    )
  )
)
```

If you want to include your `input$nRV` (as mentioned in comments), use a `reactive` expression, and call it as `my_data()`:

```
server <- function(input, output) { 
  my_data <- reactive({ 
    a = rnorm(input$nRV, mean = 2) 
    b = rnorm(input$nRV, mean = 5) 
    x = rnorm(input$nRV, mean = 3) 
    y = rnorm(input$nRV, mean = 0) 
    z = rnorm(input$nRV, mean = 0.5)
    data.frame(a, b, x, y, z)
  }) 

  output$table <- renderTable({ data.frame(my_data()$x, my_data()$y, my_data()$z) 
  }) 

  output$plot <- renderPlot({ plot(my_data()$x, my_data()$y) }) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestions. I re-watched the entire video and this time I understood the reactive values a lot more with your practical example.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to stack overflow and programming in general.

Comment: So I'm still stuck on this problem. Your code runs just fine but when I try to use the input variables I get the error that I'm trying to do something that can only be done in a reactive object.

Comment: Feel free to revise your question with additional code or ask new question. Happy to provide further assistance if I can.

Comment: server <- function(input, output) {
   my_data <- reactiveValues(
    a <- rnorm(input$nRV, mean = 2),
    b <- rnorm(input$nRV, mean = 5),
    x = rnorm(input$nRV, mean = 3),
    y = rnorm(input$nRV, mean = 0),
    z = rnorm(input$nRV, mean = 0.5)
  )
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    data.frame(my_data$x, my_data$y, my_data$z)
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(my_data$x, my_data$y)
  })
  
  
}

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to paste the code but I can't put it in a block like above anymore for some reason

Comment: If you use `input$nRV` you may want a `reactive` function and not `reactiveValues`...I'll edit the answer above.